# Deleting the listings that is filtered while producing an output

Tags: command-line, files

I have a directory with a bunch of files extensions mixed and I would like to list a specific file extension (maybe something like `grep *.mp3`) and while listing, delete them with an output. How can I do that or if there's a dupe, please feel free to tag me in.

Example:

```
grep "*.mp3" . | rm -fr
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's start with a directory with three `mp3` files:

```
$ ls *mp3
a.mp3  b.mp3  c.mp3
```

Now, let's delete them after we list what we are deleting:

```
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*.mp3' -printf 'Deleting %p\n' -delete
Deleting ./a.mp3
Deleting ./b.mp3
Deleting ./c.mp3
```

After this is done, the `mp3` files are gone:

```
$ ls *mp3
ls: cannot access '*mp3': No such file or directory
```

#### How it works

- `find .

  This starts a `find` command.  It will look for files in the current directory, `.`.
- `-maxdepth 1`

  By default, `find` recursively searches subdirectories.  This tells it not to do that.  With `-maxdepth 1`, the command `find` will only look at what it finds in the current directory and not explore any of the current directory's subdirectories.
- `-name '*.mp3'`

  This tells find to look only for files with the `.mp3` extension.
- `-printf 'Deleting %p\n'`

  This tells find to print a message about each file found.

  You can, of course, change this to another message if you like.  If you don't want a message, then this option can be omitted entirely.
- `-delete`

  This tells find to delete each file.

#### Case insensitive search

If you also want to find files named `.MP3` or `.Mp3` etc., then we need a case-insensitive search and we use `-iname`:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -iname '*.mp3' -printf 'Deleting %p\n' -delete
```

Comment: `-iname` seems better because there are MP3 files that end in `.MP3`.

Comment: @edwinksl OK.  I added that to the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! worked perfectly... I though of the `find` command but no sure why I haven't gone this route. BTW, I'm pretty confused about `-maxdepth 1` on **This tells it not to.h 1**. I'm lost at and would you mind repeating the explanation a bit, please.

Comment: Okay! I figured out looking the other user's answer. Thank you BTW.

Comment: @AzkerM Oops: something went wrong with my editing there!  Answer updated. Glad you figured it figured out anyway.

Comment: How about using using the built-in `-printf 'Deleting %f\n'` instead of `-exec echo {} \;`?

Comment: @steeldriver Very good.  I like it.  Answer updated.

Answer (score 4):

You want `find`...

```
find . -type f -iname "*.mp3"
```

By default it will recurse to subdirectories, so if you are getting more files than you want, add `-maxdepth 1` to search in the current directory only. After checking that the output is what you want to delete, you can do it again (thank you up-arrow...) and add `-delete`.

```
find . -type f -iname "*.mp3" -delete
```

`.` is the current working directory - you can give the path to the directory here instead if you are not in it...

To make it interactive, you could use `-exec` to define your own action instead of `find`'s `-delete` action

```
find . -type f -iname "*.mp3" -exec rm -i -- {} \;
```

Then it will prompt you before deleting each file...

Comment: Thank you for your explanation too. Now I understood why `-maxdepth 1` is used. This is to pretty much stay in the current directory. ^_^

Comment: yes @AzkerM or to stay in the directory specified (you could give a path instead of the current dir like `find ~/Downloads -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname "*.mp3"`) and not go into any subdirectories :)

Comment: Yes, specifying the directory path is pretty clear to me but the `-maxdepth 1` actually made sense to me now. You're good at explaining and Kudos to that :)

Comment: :D thanks @AzkerM & thanks for the nice question

Comment: Well, it was a stupid question I know but the explaining makes it understand more on what we actually do. That's what matters to me most than typing a bunch of commands... :D

Comment: Not stupid at all! I feel the same way about explanations :) @AzkerM

Comment: I think this best answers the spirit of the question asked (although the question is grammatically challenged )

Comment: Many thanks @ElderGeek :) Much appreciate your kind comment.

Answer (score 3):

When you want to delete only items in current directory, it is sufficient to use the wildcard like so:

```
$ ls *.jpeg
birthday2016_001.jpeg  birthday2016_002.jpeg  birthday2016_003.jpeg
$ rm *.jpeg
$ ls *.jpeg
ls: cannot access '*.jpeg': No such file or directory
```

As you can see, in the example above, all files with `.jpeg` extension got removed. Listing them , is the same idea - `echo *.jpeg` and `ls *.jpeg`. So you essentially could do simply `ls *.mp3 && rm *.mp3` for your case

#### Python alternative:

In my case, I was removing `.jpeg` file, so adjust the code below as necessary:

```
 python -c 'import os,sys;[(sys.stdout.write(i + "\n"),os.unlink(i)) for i in os.listdir(".")  if i.endswith(".jpeg")]'
```

Sample run:

```
$ ls *.jpeg
birthday2016_001.jpeg  birthday2016_002.jpeg  birthday2016_003.jpeg     
$ python -c 'import os,sys;[(sys.stdout.write(i + "\n"),os.unlink(i)) for i in os.listdir(".")  if i.endswith(".jpeg")]'
birthday2016_003.jpeg
birthday2016_001.jpeg
birthday2016_002.jpeg
$ ls *.jpeg
ls: cannot access '*.jpeg': No such file or directory
```

Comment: Thank you for simplifying it. `ls *.mp3 && rm *.mp3` actually make sense.. didn't think of this way at all.. Also, thank you for the python alternative, I should get myself a little knowledge on python.. :)